# How to combine two columns in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two column in sql

```
year    month
2016    4
2014    5
```

What I want to do now is to combine these two columns together and get the period

Output

```
year    month    result 
2016    4        201604
2014    5        201405
```

Are there ways to do this?

Comment: Column data types? If integer, do `year * 100 + month`, if character do `year + month`.

Comment: @jarlh nice trick with the numbers!

Comment: @jarlh, post that as answer.

Comment: @jarlh thanks. this is a good answer as well, never thought of this one

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If the column data types are integer, do

```
select year * 100 + month from tablename
```

Comment: For better understanding `(year * 100) + month`

Answer (score 3):

First, you need to `CAST` them to `VARCHAR` to allow concatenation. Then use `RIGHT` for `month` to pad the value with `0`:

```
WITH Tbl AS(
    SELECT 2016 AS [year], 4 AS [month] UNION ALL
    SELECT 2014, 5
)
SELECT *,
    CAST([year] AS VARCHAR(4)) + RIGHT('0' + CAST([month] AS VARCHAR(2)), 2)
FROM Tbl
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming both columns are numeric types:

```
SELECT year, 
       month,
       CAST(year as char(4)) + RIGHT('00' + CAST(month as varchar(2)), 2) as result
FROM YourTable
```